Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies
I am encountering an issue with a custom MSBuild task in my C# project. The task, HitcMacroTest.PreprocessTask, is defined in the HitcMacroTest assembly. However, when I build my project, WinFormsApp1, I get the following error:
MSB4062 The "HitcMacroTest.PreprocessTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly
\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\HitcMacroTest.dll. Could not load file or assembly
'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or 
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the 
<UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are 
available, and that the task contains a public class that implements 
Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. 
WinFormsApp1    \Macro\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1.csproj 28  

Both HitcMacroTest and WinFormsApp1 projects target .NET 8.0.
My WinFormsApp1.cspoj file code
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="17.10.4" />
</ItemGroup>

<UsingTask TaskName="HitcMacroTest.PreprocessTask" AssemblyFile="F:\PROJECTS\Macro\WinFormsApp1\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\HitcMacroTest.dll" />

<ItemGroup>
<PreprocessSources Include="F:\PROJECTS\Macro\**\*.cs" Exclude="$(PreprocessedOutputDirectory)\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\HitcMacroTest\HitcMacroTest.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PreprocessMacros" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
<MakeDir Directories="$(PreprocessedOutputDirectory)" />
<PreprocessTask InputFiles="@(PreprocessSources)" 
OutputDirectory="$(PreprocessedOutputDirectory)" />
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Remove="@(PreprocessSources)" />
<Compile Include="$(PreprocessedOutputDirectory)\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
</Target>


If i recall correctly task for msbuild 17 needed to be written in Net 6. I might be wrong here looking at the docu.

@Ralf do you mean it will not work in .net 8.0

@Ralf To target net8.0, must use version 17.8 or later. I am using Version 17.9.4

You can build net 8 for sure with msbuild we all do that all the time but that does not mean the task created to be used by msbuild couldn't have other specific requirements. The last time i did that it needed to be Net 6 but that might have been changed the documentation wasn't to clear to me about that.

@pramodmaurya I am curious how you made out. I am trying to figure out the same exact issue and I am targeting Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core 17.8.3
